# Which mobile clients allow payments using Near Field Communications (NFC)?

Tags: client, mobile, nfc

Which Bitcoin apps (or mobile-enabled websites) support the ability to pay using Near Field Communications (NFC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas Schildbach's [open-source](https://github.com/Goonie/Bitcoin-Wallet-for-Android) [Bitcoin wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) supports this feature. With the "Request bitcoins" screen open, tap another device to send it the `bitcoin:` URI to send to (that opens the "Send bitcoins" screen on the other device). You can also scan an NFC tag containing a `bitcoin:` URI to open the "Send bitcoins" screen with the fields filled in.